# argv somehow never matches the input

Tags: c, cs50, argv

In the code below, strings in **argv** never matches the user input strings.

For example, if I execute a code with line `./plurality Alice Bob`, the names in **argc** are correctly transferred to the `candidates` array, but they just never match with the strings that is received later in the program. *(Unnecessary part of the programs were removed, for the sake of readability.)*

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        printf("%s ", candidates[i].name);
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].name == name)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is driving me crazy, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The global variable `int candidate_count` in implicitly initialized to 0 so you want to assign it a value if you want something  else. Consider using argc in your loop condition, you need to anyways, to safely index `argv[i + 1]`.
2. Use `!strcmp()` to compare two strings for equality.
3. (Advise) Don't use global variables.
4. (Not fixed) Consider using `lfind()`in `vote()`.
5. (Idea) It will not be faster till probably 1,000+ votes but you could also sort your candidate array (`qsort()`) and use binary search (`bsearch()`).  Alternatively keep the array sorted as you add candidates.  The insight here is that number of candidates is probably much smaller than number of votes.
6. (Idea) Consider using a struct of arrays instead of array of structs:

```
struct candidates {
   string *names;
   int *votes;
}
```

It's a little more work to dynamically allocate the names and votes array, but it maps more directly to your problem including your search use case.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 9

typedef char * string;
typedef struct {
    string name;
    int votes;
} candidate;

bool vote(size_t len, candidate candidates[len], string name) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (!strcmp(candidates[i].name, name)) {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    size_t candidate_count = argc - 1;
    // if(candidate_count > MAX) {
    //  printf("too many candidates\n");
    //  return 1;
    // }
    candidate candidates[candidate_count];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        printf("%s ", candidates[i].name);
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++) {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");
        if (!vote(candidate_count, candidates, name)) {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`canidates[i].name == name` Compares the addresses of the two strings.

Use `strcmp()` instead.